# In Entity Framework Core, if I define these relationships, will it create a cyclic relationship between two entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-core, relational-database

I have an event scheduling app with a SQL Server database. It is running as part of an ASP.NET web app using Entity Framework Core. It has the following tables/entities:

- `User`: may join many events as a participant
- `Event`: may have many users as participants. It's also created by a single user

This many-to-many relationship can be resolved using a join table: `UserEvent`.

[I end up with this relationship diagram.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtAbq.png)

However, my problem is that I am not sure that it is okay if a single `User` is linked to a single `Event` twice, both as a participant and as a creator. The creator of the event would have their ID stored as a FK in the `Event` they created and they would have their ID stored as a FK in the `UserEvent` that registers them as a participant of the `Event`. The app assumes if they create the event, they are attending it.

Is there a better way to configure this relationship?

When I try to add the migration I get the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Events_MyUsers_CreatorID' on table 'Events' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Here is an example of my code:

`User` model:

```
public class User
{
    public User() {
        UserName = "Default";
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Event>? UserEvents { get; set; }
}
```

`Event` model:

```
public class Event
{
    public Event() 
    {
        EventName = "Default Event Name";
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long CreatorID { get; set; }
    public User Creator { get; set; }

    public virtual List<User> EventUsers { get; set; }

    public string EventName { get; set; }
}
```

Override of `OnModelCreating` method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) 
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<User>(
            b => {
                b.Property(user => user.ID)
                    .IsRequired();

                b.Property(user => user.UserName)
                    .IsRequired();

                b.HasKey(user => user.ID);

                b.HasMany(user => user.UserEvents)
                 .WithMany(e => e.EventUsers)
                 .UsingEntity(join => join.ToTable("UserEvents"));

                b.ToTable("MyUsers");
            });

    builder.Entity<Event>(
            b => {
                b.Property(e => e.ID)
                    .IsRequired();

                b.Property(e => e.EventName)
                    .IsRequired();

                b.Property(e => e.CreatorID)
                    .IsRequired();

                b.HasKey(e => e.ID);

                b.HasMany(e => e.EventUsers)
                 .WithMany(user => user.UserEvents)
                 .UsingEntity(join => join.ToTable("UserEvents"));

                b.HasOne(e => e.Creator)
                 .WithMany();

                b.ToTable("Events");
            });
}
```

When I remove the `CreatorID` and `Creator` columns from the `Event` table, it migrates fine.

How can I reorganize my relationships to get allow events to have a `Creator` field and/or track which `User` created an `Event`?

---

@SNBS Deserves all credit for the answer. See their post below. I had to tweak their code to get it to compile.

To avoid the relationship detailed in the question it was necessary to add a BIT field to the `UserEvent` table to represent the user "Role" within that event.

To ensure that an `Event` could not have more than one creator I had to add a custom SQL function and enforce it as a constraint on the `UserEvent` table.

This explanation assumes you're using Visual Studio.

### Custom Function

If you are new to SQL Server like me you might wonder how to add the function. In visual studio within the SQL Server Object Explorer. Right click on: `Programmability->Functions -> Add New Scalar Valued Function`.

After writing the code in the new window make sure to click "Update Database" and check your code compiles. If it works you should be able to see you new function in the explorer.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION CheckOneCreator (@EventId BIGINT)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
-- Create and open a cursor
DECLARE Participants CURSOR
FOR
SELECT UserID
FROM UserEvents
WHERE EventID = @EventId;
OPEN Participants;

-- Creators count
DECLARE @CreatorsCount INT;
SELECT @CreatorsCount = 0;

-- Iterate over participants
DECLARE @ParticipantId BIGINT;

FETCH NEXT FROM Participants
INTO @ParticipantId;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
-- Check whether the participant is the creator
DECLARE @IsCreator BIT;

SELECT @IsCreator = (
SELECT TOP 1 IsCreator
FROM UserEvents
WHERE UserID = @ParticipantId
AND EventID = @EventId
);

-- Increase creators count
IF @IsCreator = 1 SELECT @CreatorsCount = (@CreatorsCount + 1);

FETCH NEXT FROM Participants
INTO @ParticipantId;
END

IF @CreatorsCount = 1 RETURN 1;
RETURN 0;
END
```

### Add Constraint

To add this function as a constraint right click on your database in the SQL Object Explorer in Visual Studio and select `New Object`. A code window will open. Once you type your code in, once again ensure you click "Update Database" and check to see if your code compiles. If successful, you will see the constraint added under the constraints folder for the table.

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserEvents]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [SingleCreator] CHECK ([dbo].[CheckOneCreator]([EventID])=(1));
```

Comment: why not give a try and then see

Comment: @viveknuna Hi thanks for your response. I have tried and got the included error message. I have also looked around at other Q/A on here as well as read several articles about relationships in databases. They mostly cover the three types of relationship but don't help me answer my question. In addition I have spent a long time reading the EF docs and have seen that you can make entities owned but I don't think it fits my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better if each user had a *role* (creator or general participant) in all events he takes part in. You may create a new column in table `UserEvent` and name it `IsCreator` (data type — `bit`, which is the SQL equivalent of .NET type `bool`). This column should contain 0 for general participants and 1 for creators.

*UPDATE*: a constraint is necessary to check that an event can have only one creator. Firstly, create a function in your database using this SQL code:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION CheckOneCreator (@EventId BIGINT)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
-- Create and open a cursor
DECLARE Participants CURSOR
FOR
SELECT UserId
FROM UserEvent
WHERE EventId = @EventId;
OPEN Participants;

-- Creators count
DECLARE @CreatorsCount INT;
SELECT @CreatorsCount = 0;

-- Iterate over participants
DECLARE @ParticipantId BIGINT;

FETCH NEXT FROM Participants
INTO @ParticipantId;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
-- Check whether the participant is the creator
DECLARE @IsCreator BIT;

SELECT @IsCreator = (
SELECT TOP 1 IsCreator
FROM UserEvent
WHERE UserId = @ParticipantId
AND EventId = @EventId
);

-- Increase creators count
IF @IsCreator SELECT @CreatorsCount = (@CreatorsCount + 1);

FETCH NEXT FROM Participants
INTO @ParticipantId;
END

CLOSE Participants;
DEALLOCATE CURSOR Participants;

IF @CreatorsCount != 1 RETURN 0;
ELSE RETURN 1;
END
```

And define a constraint for table `UserEvent`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE UserEvent
ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK (CheckOneCreator(EventId) = 1);
```

P. S. Use this function only if you *really* don't want a user to be linked twice (because the queries take time). And create an index for columns `UserId` and `EventId` in table `UserEvent`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. However that model you suggested, am I right to think that using a bit field would mean that an event could have more than one creator?

Comment: @Fohristiwhirl Yes, forgot about that. But take a look at the update in my answer.

Comment: I will have to investigate your answer further and try some things out with it. I am new to SQL Server and do not yet know how to add functions etc. When I have time during the week I will attempt to implement your solution and then get back to you. Thanks again!

Comment: @Fohristiwhirl If you are new to SQL user-defined functions (like mine), [this](https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-sql-user-defined-functions/) may help you.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer and the update including a custom function. 

I was able to update my database as required! I spent the time to research deeper into custom SQL functions and constraints, how to add them to my database/tables and learnt more about SQL in the process. Now I feel I am more confident to deal with my database directly.

Just a note, I will update my question with your answer later. There were a few changes I had to make to get the SQL to compile so it would be good to have something I know works for other users to benefit from your answer.

Thanks again.

Comment: The two changes I had to make were: 

Remove the "ELSE" keyword from the custom function. For some reason the compiler couldn't determine if a value was being returned otherwise.

Add a constraint name: EG `ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name CHECK(CheckOneCreator(EventId) = 1);`

Comment: @Fohristiwhirl Thanks to you too, I didn't know about constraint names.

Comment: @Fohristiwhirl I'm very sorry, but I have forgotten to close and deallocate the cursor used in my function. I have updated the answer (it's correct now).

Comment: No need to worry, I didn't realize that manual de-allocation was required in SQL. I will update my code. And probably learn SQL in more detail when my current project is done. Thanks again.